# How to change StaticRouter's location prop using the <Link> tag in Server Side Rendering with React-Router

Tags: reactjs, express, redux, server-side-rendering, react-router-dom

**What already works:**

Server side rendering on home page.

**What doesn't work:**

Server side rendering on other others routes from home page by clicking on `<Link>` tags to go to other routes. Well kind of not working, kind of working at the same time.

**Kind of working?:**

If you view the page source of the page after clicking the `<Link>` you will see all the initial data that was picked up by the server side rendering, however it did not get stored in the reducers on the client side.

**Solution?:**

From a lot of time and research and asking, I have came to the conclusion that the problem is with `StaticRouter` on the server side. And in particular the `location` prop. This prop is passed the `req.path` or `req.url`, I have tried both and get the same outcome. I will use `req.path` for the example.

Let's look at this block of code here:

```
console.log(req.path);
    const content = renderToString(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <StaticRouter location={req.path} context={context}>
          <div>{renderRoutes(routes)}</div>
        </StaticRouter>
      </Provider>
    );
```

Here we log out the `req.path` before it is passed in to the `location` prop. This is what I believe is telling the router to load the correct data into the store and have it be sent to the client side reducers.

I will take a step by step of what happens for the app flow.

On `/` route load `console.log(req.path)` shows this in the server side terminal:

`/`

However if I click on the `<Link to="/users">Users</Link>` for example, the console log does nothing.

Now from here I can refresh the page, and boom it works, the data is loaded and the `console.log(req.path)` shows:

`/users`

Something else I can do to make this work is directly go to the route of `localhost:3000/users` and the `console.log(req.path)` will show `/users` and the data loads correctly. But both of these way aren't really solutions and only work because they "bypass" the `<Link>` tag in a way.

**What is the question already???:**

I want to know how to use the `<Link>` tag to change the `req.path` or `req.url` since this is what I am seeing is the problem or if it is at all possible. That way the `location` prop in `StaticRouter` will be changed when the `<Link>` is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This piece of code:

```
console.log(req.path);
    const content = renderToString(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <StaticRouter location={req.path} context={context}>
          <div>{renderRoutes(routes)}</div>
        </StaticRouter>
      </Provider>
    );
```

is executed on the server side, and it happens in cases when you land on site, directly visit some page by typing url or when you refresh a page, because in those cases you "ask" server to do rendering for you.

`<Link>` is used for navigation on the browser side and it doesn't ask the server to do anything, it's all executed in the browser that's why it never triggers `console.log(req.path);`. Unless you do it explicitly, for example, refreshing page programmatically with some code like this `location.reload();`. In my opinion, if you feel the need to do something like this you are missing the point.

**SSR - long story short:**

We use SSR so we don't wait for initial HTML and initial data when we land on a page. Instead of sending blank page and letting the browser do all the work, we can render components on the server into a static mockup, the page containing repopulated data is then sent to the browser. When bundle.js comes browser takes over from that point on, taking care of navigation and loading whatever is needed for interactivity.

Some of the benefits using SSR are **fast first paint** which leads better user experience and potentially **better SEO** because crawlers better read static mockup send from server than dynamic mockup generated on client.

Comment: After some research and thinking this is the conclusion I came to is there any other way besides doing a reload? Because in that case I might as well use an `<a>` tag, or just load in the data client side with actions. But as I said it may not be possible. So is that what you are saying?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with server reload? If it is updating your store, fetching data, that is something that client should do on navigation state changed by Link.

Comment: But that defeats the entire purpose of doing SSR does it not?

Comment: It is not, we use SSR so we don't wait for initial HTML and initial data when we land on a page. Instead of sending blank page and letting the browser do all the work, we can render components on the server into a static mockup, the page containing repopulated data is then sent to the browser. 
When bundle.js comes browser takes over from that point on, taking care of navigation and loading whatever is needed for interactivity.

Comment: Can you add this to your answer and I'll accept it. Also I found that doing SSR on other routes is still beneficial for SEO stuff like crawlers and what not. Include this and I'll accept answer and give you bounty

Comment: @TaylorAustin better now?

Comment: Yes sorry about that was busy busy. I have to wait a little to give you the bounty. I'll do it when I can but I accepted the answer